# Custom Icon for default IME Actions for keyboard and edit text

Tags: android, android-layout, keyboard

I am trying to customize the IME actions of my keyboard in a messaging app. I am using IME_ACTION_SEND and i am fine with the default icon used on the keyboard but I am having trouble changing the IME action display shown in the edit text when in landscape mode. Currently the ime action button has a label that says "send" but i want it to be the send icon not the word send. I also want to keep the enter/return button on the keyboard as shown and not change that to the send icon.

[image]

An example of what I am kind of trying to do (but using an icon or drawable instead of the emoji):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Hello World!"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
            android:maxLines="4"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:imeActionLabel="@string/thumbs_up"
            android:imeOptions="actionSend|flagNoEnterAction"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

string:

```
<resources>
    <string name="thumbs_up"></string>
</resources>
```

Comment: Bear in mind that there are hundreds of input method editors. All you can do is provide hints; the developers of those input method editors will decide how to handle those hints. Note that your question does not include a [mcve].

Comment: @CommonsWare i guess the first part of your comment kind of answers my question it basically seems to be "No", i can't really do anything beyond Changing the label on that button. I did add code for a minimal reproducible example, but I did not before because I was only asking about customizing what i circled in my screen capture.

Comment: The bulk of my comment was not so much "no", as "not in any reliable fashion". Stack Overflow is notorious for "oh, use this magic recipe" that only works on a few devices, and I was anticipating that you would collect answers like that (or links to such answers). Given your code and your screenshot, the particular IME that you are using happens to want to use the word "Send" for the full-screen edition of the keyboard when you use `actionSend`. Not all IMEs will do that, and you don't have any real control over that aspect of their behavior.

Comment: Yah i understood that your answer implied that any implementation would not be a universal answer and I was hoping to get a "works for all" answer. I would be satified if i could get an answer that only worked on Samsung Board and Gboard

Answer (score 0):

I ended up setting ime_flag_no_extract_ui flag on the edit text and used a button next to my edit text.

I did consider using an emoji on the label but in the end, I was also trying to update the label in real time with a text watch but you can not make config changes to IME on the keyboard without closing and re-opening the keyboard.